# error: string indices must be integers, while unpacking request.body object from API Gateway request for a lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, api, lambda

I am trying my hands-on with API gateway as a trigger to lambda function using python as run time.

here is by python code:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    num1, num2 = event['body'][0]['num1'], event['body'][0]['num2']

    return {
        'statusCode' :200,
        'body': json.dumps({
           'num1' : num1,
           'num2' : num2,
           'result' : num1 + num2
        })
    }
```

Here is the error that I am getting when checking the cloud watch logs.

```
string indices must be integers: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/add.py", line 4, in lambda_handler
    num1, num2 = event['body'][0]['num1'], event['body'][0]['num2']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

str
```

Here is my Postman request:

[image]

Would like to mention I also tried:

```
num1, num2 = event['body']['num1'], event['body']['num2']
```

Gave the same error.

I know I am missing something while unpacking them, but not able to point it out.

could anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Your `event['body']` is probably a json string. Can you try `json.loads(event['body'])` to convert the string to json before you attempt to access its elements?

Comment: @Marcin Thank you I was able to unpack, but still facing issues with return portion of the code

Comment: Can you update your question with how `json.loads(event['body'])` looks likes like?

Comment: @Marcin have the changes

Comment: There is spelling mistake `ststudCode`. Should be `statusCode`

Comment: So silly of me. Thank you @Marcin, as always :) Have a safe and good day

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference :-)

Comment: sure, please i'll also correct my spelling

Comment: @Marcin could you help me out of this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577704/adding-ssl-certificate-issues-by-acm-to-apache-virtual-host-on-ubuntu-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

There were **two issues**:

1. `event['body']` was string, not json. It was solved using `json.loads(event['body'])`.
2. A spelling mistake in `ststudCode`. It should be `statusCode`.