# Adding SSL certificate issues by ACM to Apache virtual host on ubuntu machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate, apache2

I am trying my Hands-on ACM for SSL certificates.

I have requested a public certificate for a domain 'prod.yp-uae.waveaxis.space' which is attached to a
load balancer. I have also added the Https listener to the load balancer.

The ACM dashboard shows the certificate to be in use.

But when I use the domain name in the browser it shows not normal non-secure link http://prod.yp-uae.waveaxis.space/

I assume it is because of the virtual host that I have set on apache2.
Below is the code for my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


        ServerName prod.yp-uae.waveaxis.space
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyPreserveHost On
            
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8380/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8380/
        
</VirtualHost>
    
#<VirtualHost *:443>
#</VirtualHost>
```

I am aware of configuring 443 port as below(just an example)

```
SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
  SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/www.foo.com/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/www.foo.com/ssl/server.key"
```

The thing I am wondering on is how can I get my ACM SSL certificate on my Ec2 machine for the variable
**'SSLCertificateFile' 'SSLCertificateKeyFile'**?

OR

Am I missing some other part as well?

Here is my ALB's security group:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Marcin answer based on our discussion you need to ensure that you serve assets and reference domains in your JavaScript to use a HTTPS protocol and not a HTTP protocol (as is currently being used).

If the user is accessing the site over HTTPS, any requests using HTTP may be blocked due to "Mixed Content" which would then stop your site from loading these resources. This would have worked when the site is also loaded over plain text (HTTP).

If these also load over HTTPS then Marcins solution will work for you. In addition you are referencing an IP address rather than a domain that can serve the HTTPS request, this should be adjusted as I am assuming this is the IP of an EC2 host rather than the load balancer.

Comment: thank you for the answer. We are going ahead with your suggestion to add a load balancer in front of our app server.
While doing this I have to add an SSL certificate to it. My ACM certificate while creating i gave the Domain name of only the front end load balancer. Now will the same ACM certificate will work if I attach it to backend ELB which has a different domain name?This name was not  given  while creating the ACM certificate

Comment: @Chris Do we need to add anything to SSLCertificateFile & SSLCertificateKey?? in ssl.conf

Answer (score 1):

Generally you **don't need SSL cert on your EC2 instances** if you have deployed SSL cert on your ALB. The reason is that ALB is going to **terminate** your SSL/HTTPS connection, and then it will forward it to your instances as a regular HTTP (non-SSL) connection. In this scenario, the traffic flow is:

```
client---(HTTPS)-->ALB----(HTTP)--->EC2 instances
```

This design **simplifies** a lot of work with manually setting up SSL certificates and off-loads its processing to ALB.

Therefore,  if its not really a requirement to have HTTPS between ALB and instance, its just easier to have your Apache serve regular **HTTP traffic on port 80**.

> The thing I am wondering on is how can I get my ACM SSL certificate

Sadly you **can't access** ACM certificates as they [can only be used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html) on load balancer, CloudFront distribution and API gateway. This means that you **can't use it on  instances**.

However, if you really require end-to-end HTTPS, then you should generate and deploy your own **self-signed SSL** certificate on the instances. This will require a bit of setup, but your connection will be:

```
client---(HTTPS)-->ALB----(HTTPS)--->EC2 instances
```

However, this is not normally done and in most cases the first scenario with HTTP between ALB and the instance is sufficient.

Comment: thank you for the answer it cleared a lot of things. 
But when I access my domain it's still showing not secure like basic HTTP. 
How can I send an https request to test if it is really working?

Comment: @sumanthshetty You can update the question with your listener and target group setup. Also have you open port 443 on the ALB's security group?

Comment: done. Please let me know if anything else is required

Comment: @sumanthshetty Your 443 listener should forward to `yp-tg-elb`, not to its https variant. Can you please try that?

Comment: Still getting not secure.
Should my target group have 443 port configured as well?

Comment: @sumanthshetty It works for me. Are you sure you are trying with https: `https://prod.yp-uae.waveaxis.space/` ? Also you can try deleting your browser cashe.

Comment: It did work. 
But there is a difference between https://prod.yp-uae.waveaxis.space/ and http://prod.yp-uae.waveaxis.space/. 

Https site is not loading properly, why could that be?

Comment: @sumanthshetty Glad to hear. I don't know why it would be different. I don't think its ALB related. Maybe some CORS issue? I see in browser console: `Blocked loading mixed active content ` as it seems you have some files loaded using http, other files loaded https. Anyway, glad it worked out. Now you have to amend your website to uniformly use https. Its not something ALB can do for you.

Comment: just to clarify the issue at hand. If this is the case client---(HTTPS)-->ALB----(HTTP)--->EC2 instances, then both HTTP and https should be working right?